# How to convert NSString into NSDate

Tags: ios, uilabel, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I want to convert my label.text into `NSDate` My formatter is `MM/dd/yyyy`. So I convert it like this.

```
 mydate1=[dateFormatter dateFromString:depdate1txt.text];
```

My label value is `(lldb) po depdate1txt.text
12/13/2015`

But when I check the `mydate1` it shows as `(lldb) po mydate1
2015-12-12 18:30:00 +0000`

Why date has changed into 12th december in 2015?
Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: which DateFormat and timezone you used in your dateformatter?

Comment: show your full tried code

Comment: So you are located in India. Your time is 5:30 ahead of UTC.

Answer (score 0):

When you print the date with po it's not formatting it - that's the base value. All dates are stored as a timestamp and only formatted when you explicitly format them.

The `po` command just takes a default formatter to show the date.

Oh, and the 'date change' is because of your timezone - the printed date is GMT +0.